# Subclass int to allow "unknown" value

Tags: python, int, subclass

I'm kind of stuck here.  I'm basically at experimenting phase and I wonder if I can subclass `int` so that it will act exactly as your good old `int`, except that you will be able to assign an "unknown" value which, in case of arithmetic operations, will act as 1.

So that I could say:

```
>>> uint(5) + 5
10
>>> uint('unknown')
unknown
>>> int(uint('unknown'))
1
>>> uint('unknown') + 5
6
>>>
```

In fact, it's somehow similar to what already works with `float('inf')`, except that I only need integer plus the single "special" value.

What I was imagining to work would be something along the lines:

```
class uint(int):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.unknown = self.value == "unknown"

    def __int__(self):
        return 1 if self.unknown else self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return "unknown" if self.unknown else str(self.value)
```

but this example throws `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'unknown'` when I try to instantiate it as `uint('unknown')`.

So is this possible?  How would I go about that?

---

**background level 1**

In case someone asks, the background is that I have a list of iterables and I want to create new one using `itertools.product`.  But before, I want to make use of `__len__`, in case some iterators implement it, to be able to guess (minimal) number of final elements.  So in terms of the final number, for those iterables that don't have the `__len__`, I'm assuming 1.

Reason why I want to do this with `class uint(int)` is that I want to be able to expose the separate counts safely (so that someone can push in log something like: "loading (1500 = 10 * 10 * unknown * 15) elements" and still pass on the information that some of them are "unknown".

**background level 2**

I'm actually fancying a situation when the a library provides this class for use in definition of iterable objects' `__len__`, so that they can be returning a number based either on "minimum", "maximum" or "best guess", while still not being bothered by its further use in some simple maths.

```
>>> count = uint(100, 'minimum')
>>> print count
"minimum of 100"
>>> count * 20
2000
>>>
```

Imagine an object with an iterator that reads a huge file: why couldn't the object say "well, the file is 400 MiB, so there will be at least 4,000 records"?

So a bonus question: What is simpler: subclassing int or creating a new class but having to implement and maintain interface for aritmethic operations?

Comment: Why `1`? What's the semantics behind this? Also, how is this different than having an `int` field which can also be `None`?

Comment: If you are looking for ways to handle values in a set of observations that are unknown, there are many standard ways to handle that. But that would be a different question than what you asked.

Comment: I've read your added "backgrounds" thrice and it does not seem to make your intended goal any more clear. However "should I subclass int" is more obviously "no". Whatever your "unknown" is, it fails the "**is-a** int" test of OO Design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you would want to do this, but the following should work:

```
class uint(int):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        unknown = value == 'unknown'
        obj = super(uint, cls).__new__(cls, 1 if unknown else value)
        obj.unknown = unknown
        return obj

    def __str__(self):
        return 'unknown' if self.unknown else super(uint, self).__str__()
```

The idea here is that instead of storing your int value in a property called `self.value`, you perform the instantiation of the super class with the value you want to use.

Comment: Well, this works.  Except that after reading msw's comments and answer, I'm probably re-thinking my strategy, but your solution works, and tells me how to break the mathematics. Accepting.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some conceptual problems which trump your implementation issues.

Treating "unknown values" as 1 makes them not really unknown. To draw an analogy to floating point numbers, there is a well defined ["Not a Number"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) which will participate in math operations but in most cases yield NaN. For example:

```
>>> f = float('NaN')
>>> 42 * f
nan
```

This is a Good Thing because NaN really is not a number so arithmetic using it should not generate seemingly valid results. If you implemented your "unknown integer" as you propose, unknown values would yield nonsensical results. For example:

```
>>> u = uint('unknown')
>>> 42 * u
42
```

You get back a proper integer, but is that really the semantics that you want? Another similar case is division by zero which is mathematically undefined. Any value that could be kludged into place would yield mathematical absurdities. Since `(x/y) * y == x` (if and only if `y != 0`) you might expect that:

```
>>> (42 / 0) * 0   # this doesn't really work
42
```

But you can't do that without breaking mathematics.

Comment: Because of your answer I immediately went into the Python interpreter and typed in `x = (42 / 0) * 0` and expected to get 42 as some sort of hidden easter egg. I was very disappointed. :( +1 anyways.

Comment: You thought it would yield the answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything? Sorry to disappoint ;) I've made it more clearly invalid, thanks for the implied correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `None` as a placeholder for a value that isn't assigned yet. For example:

```
>>> a = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2, None, None]
>>> len(a)
7
>> a*3
[4, 3, 1, 5, 2, None, None, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, None, None, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, None, None]
```